# Is it possible to send text data with the image alongside in Alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I need to send some text data alongside with the image(multipart) via Alamofire, for example:

```
{
    "name": "Me",
    "age":  "23",
    "image": file_goes_here
}
```

I know how to send text data and image as multipart separately, but I do not know how can I send all it in one, the same, request. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this -

```
Alamofire.upload(.POST, urlString, headers: nil, multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) -> Void in

    multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: name.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!, name :"name")
    multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: age.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!, name :"age")
    //.....

    }, encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
        //...

        }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can encode image data to base64 format.

```
// Use image name from bundle to create NSData
let image : UIImage = UIImage(named:"imageName")!
let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
```

**Swift 2.0 Encoding**

```
let base64String = imageData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
```

**Swift 2.0 Decoding**

```
let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64String, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters)
```

Then attach the base64 string into post data

```
{
    "name": "Me",
    "age":  "23",
    "image": base64String
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to send it as multipart

Comment: @JohnDoe Sorry, I don't understand what do you mean multipart?